# How are my top tags chosen?

Tags: support

My top [question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/60494/what-kind-of-crow-is-this) is a species identificatfion question with the fitting tag and 10 votes. Yet "toxicology" was and is shown as my top tag in my profile. Then all my tags were set to zero, possibly due to my initiating a bounty. Is my identification question exempt because it was deemed duplicate?

Answer (score 2):

It's just based on your participation in topics involving those tags.

You can see your # of posts under each tag on your [user page](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users/26292/ludi). You'll see that there isn't much point in focusing on your "top tag" at the moment because you have 1 post in many different tags; essentially they are all tied for the top, but it only shows one as a 'top tag'.

Comment: So scores are irrelevant?